# Construct a converging series that is substantially larger than a given converging series

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

This is more of a request for advice than a request for solution.  Last night we were given the following and nobody figured it out in the time given (about 5 minutes).  I think this is a problem many students encountered in series:  how do you recognize quickly what series you are supposed to compare to?  Is it just a matter of seeing enough of them?

Let $\{a_k\}$ be a strictly positive sequence in $\mathbb R$ such that $ \sum_k^{\infty} a_k$ converges.  Is there a sequence $\{b_k\}$ in $\mathbb R$ such that (1)  $b_k > 0$ for all $k \in \mathbb N$; (2) $\lim_{k \rightarrow \infty} {a_k \over b_k} = 0$; (3) $ \sum_k^{\infty} b_k$ converges?

Write $ S_n = \sum_k^{n} a_k$ and $S = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} S_n$. Set $b_1$ = $\sqrt{S} - \sqrt{S-S_1}$.  Then, for all $k \in \mathbb N$, set
$$b_k = \sqrt{S-S_{n-1}} - \sqrt{S-S_n} = {a_k \over \sqrt{S-S_{n-1}} + \sqrt{S-S_n}}$$
Clearly, $b_k$ is strictly positive for all $k$.  Then,
$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} {a_k \over b_k} = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \sqrt{S-S_{n-1}}+ \sqrt{S-S_n} = 0$$
Finally, $ \sum_k^{\infty} b_k = \sqrt{S} - \sqrt{S-S_1} + \sqrt{S-S_1} - \sqrt{S-S_2} ... \sqrt{S-S_{n-1}} - \sqrt{S-S_n} = \sqrt{S}$ as $n$ goes to infinity.

Comment: IMHO, after learning enough about series one should have the immediate gut feeling that the answer to the question is definitely "yes". But I doubt that everyone can be expected to come up with a general proof within five minutes. Then again, one may have the idea (in this short time frame) that one should work with the partial sums and "tear them apart". Details what to try in order to make the tearing effect stronger and stronger the closer one gets to the limit may take a while to elaborate. Then again, the infinite slope of $\sqrt x$ at $x=0$ might indeed readily come to ones mind ...

Comment: One approach to problems like these is: "I'm going to make $b_k=1a_k$ for a while, then $b_k=2a_k$ for a while, then $b_k=3a_k$ for a while, etc. - where the multiplier increases slowly enough that I don't break convergence." One can break up the $\sum a_k$ series into intervals on which the sum over the $j$th interval is less than a constant times $2^{-j}$, say, and use those intervals to choose the multipliers. I think that's a lot easier to come up with than the proof you listed, which is slick but pretty unmotivated.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Greg Martin: the given proof is not something that most people come  up with in five minutes. A widely useful approach, also mentioned by Greg Martin, is to partition the set of indices  so as to have exponential decay of remainder.

Formally: for every $j$ choose $n_j$    so that $\sum_{k>n_j} a_k<2^{-j}$, and also  $n_{j}>n_{j-1}$.  Define $b_k=ja_k$ for $n_j\le k<n_{j+1}$. Then $a_k/b_k\to 0$. Also, $\sum_{n_j\le k<n_{j+1}} b_k < j\,2^{-j}$, and summing over $j$ we get a finite number.

It helps that all terms are positive, so that  they can be grouped at will.